# windows batch-file: how to set errorlevel if string exists in file

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a windows batch-file, I want to 'EXIT 0' if the text 'no errors found' exists in a file 'output.txt'. And otherwise 'EXIT 1'.

I'm sure this is easy, but I can't work it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FIND command sets those errorlevels by default

```
@find "no errors found" "c:\the.file"
exit %errorlevel%
```